# Read an XML node value by chunks

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file with a node having enough information to get me an `OutOfMemoryException` whenever I tried to read its value directly at once. Besides the file being exported data from a database from an external service I don't control the size of this *node value* and it can be larger an larger at any time.

So what I have is something like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <MODULE>
        <ROW>
            <PROPERTY1>
                .....
            </PROPERTY1>
            .....
            <DATA>
                ENOUGH_LARGE_DATA_TO_GET_ME_AN_OUTOFMEMORYEXCEPTION_WHICH_CAN_BE_LARGER_AND_LARGER
            </DATA>
        </ROW>
    </MODULE>
    ....
</ROOT>
```

And I'm doing something like this for read the XML file by chunks:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> ElementsNamed(this XmlReader reader, string elementName)
{
    reader.MoveToContent(); // will not advance reader if already on a content node; if successful, ReadState is Interactive
    reader.Read();          // this is needed, even with MoveToContent and ReadState.Interactive
    while(!reader.EOF && reader.ReadState == ReadState.Interactive)
    {
        if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if(reader.Name.Equals(elementName))
            {
                // this advances the reader...so it's either XNode.ReadFrom() or reader.Read(), but not both
                var matchedElement = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                if(matchedElement != null)
                    yield return matchedElement;
            }
        }
        else
            reader.Read();
    }
}
```

My problem is `XNode.ReadFrom` read all the value in the node and at this point I can't get to read this value by chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't treat or even call that as an XML, I would treat it as a regular text file and use StreamReader to read it.

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.readchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actually it is a more complex XML that what I've presented here and I have to know which node I'm reading, it is possible to do so using StreamReader? Look at my edited XML exemple.